# Accumulate 2D points that have the same first component

Tags: plotting

I have a list of points:

```
points={{3, 0}, {3, 9}, {4, 2}, {5, 5}, {6, 9}, {6, 6}, {6, 1}, {7, 7}, {8,0}, {8, 10}};
```

[image]

And as you can see on the plot, there are some values of x that appear more than once.

I want to accumulate the ones that are at the same value of x, so the final result should look like this:

[image]

I tried using

```
points[[All,1]]//Split
```

To get

```
{{3, 3}, {4}, {5}, {6, 6, 6}, {7}, {8, 8}}
```

But I don't know where to go after that, furthermore, I'm fairly sure this is not the right way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works just fine for a few points:

```
acc = points //. {a___, {x_, y1_}, {x_, y2_}, 
    b___} :> {a, {x, y1 + y2}, b}

{{3, 9}, {4, 2}, {5, 5}, {6, 16}, {7, 7}, {8, 10}}
```

More efficient:

```
acc = Plus @@ #/{Length[#], 1} & /@ GatherBy[points, First]

{{3, 9}, {4, 2}, {5, 5}, {6, 16}, {7, 7}, {8, 10}}

ListLinePlot[acc]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

```
f[{a_, b_}] := {First@a, Tr@b}
f /@ Transpose /@ GatherBy[points, First]
```

**Edit**
Probably much faster:

```
s[points_] := Module[{p = points, f},
  f[_] = 0;
  Scan[f@#[[1]] += #[[2]] &, p];
  f
  ]
k = s[points];
ListLinePlot[{#, k@#} & /@ points[[All, 1]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Kuba done :),thanks

Comment: @Kuba I ommited the part that's practically the same as your answer there :)

Comment: I've seen :) +1ed there :)