# Merging lists and adding common elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two 2D arrays where some of the x-values are identical,

```
L={{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}};
J={{0,1},{2,2},{4,4}};
```

I want to add these lists in the following way

```
{{0,1}, {1,1},{2,4},{3,3},{4,4}};
```

In other words, that y-values of the data points that have the same x are added. How can I achieve this?

---

**Please note that the arrays are not necessarily of the same length**

Two arrays for test:

```
first = {{0.15, 0.000470185}, {0.16, 0.000521784}, {0.17, 0.000580663}, {0.18,
   0.000648083}, {0.19, 0.000725569}, {0.2, 0.000814968}, {0.21, 
  0.000918532}, {0.22, 0.00103901}, {0.23, 0.0011798}, {0.24, 
  0.00134508}, {0.25, 0.00154005}, {0.26, 0.00177121}, {0.27, 
  0.00204667}, {0.28, 0.00237667}, {0.29, 0.00277409}, {0.3, 
  0.00325523}, {0.31, 0.00384059}, {0.32, 0.00455591}, {0.33, 
  0.00543312}, {0.34, 0.00651098}, {0.35, 0.00783476}, {0.36, 
  0.00945361}, {0.37, 0.0114133}, {0.38, 0.0137402}, {0.39, 
  0.0164132}, {0.4, 0.0193217}, {0.41, 0.0222235}, {0.42, 
  0.0247384}, {0.43, 0.0264243}, {0.44, 0.0269371}, {0.45, 
  0.0261818}, {0.46, 0.024341}, {0.47, 0.0217652}, {0.48, 
  0.0188176}, {0.49, 0.0157753}, {0.5, 0.0128044}, {0.51, 
  0.00998009}, {0.52, 0.00731676}, {0.53, 0.00479353}, {0.54, 
  0.00237078}, {0.55, 0}}


second = {{-0.04, -0.0000547619}, {-0.03, -0.000405238}, {-0.02, -0.00207438}, \
{-0.01, -0.00878929}, {0, -0.0154401}, {0.01, -0.0178195}, {0.02, \
-0.0180879}, {0.03, -0.0173267}, {0.04, -0.0157714}, {0.05, \
-0.014605}, {0.06, -0.0131757}, {0.07, -0.0119764}, {0.08, \
-0.010695}, {0.09, -0.00946286}, {0.1, -0.00849357}, {0.11, \
-0.00708071}, {0.12, -0.00578286}, {0.13, -0.00468214}, {0.14, \
-0.00306119}, {0.15, -0.00146214}, {0.16, 0.00061881}, {0.17, 
  0.00194733}, {0.18, 0.00376762}, {0.19, 0.00509833}, {0.2, 
  0.00625381}, {0.21, 0.00762286}, {0.22, 0.00918905}, {0.23, 
  0.0105964}, {0.24, 0.0118067}, {0.25, 0.0134238}, {0.26, 
  0.0149774}, {0.27, 0.0163519}, {0.28, 0.017469}, {0.29, 
  0.0167517}, {0.3, 0.0102788}, {0.31, 0.00253876}, {0.32, 
  0.000314333}, {0.33, 0.000038881}, {0.34, 0.0000224524}}
```

---

first array is here: http://www.datafilehost.com/d/731a267e.

The second array I generate from this code:

```
factor = 11.0;
second = Table[{(38 - i)*0.01, 0}, {i, 0, 38}] - 0.04;
tempData = (1/10000) (factor/21) {
    0.41,
    0.71,
    5.74,
    46.36,
    187.70,
    305.90,
    319.0,
    298.60,
    273.50,
    245.13,
    215.60,
    193.50,
    167.80,
    139.20,
    114.20,
    93.10,
    68.80,
    35.56,
    11.30,
    -26.70,
    -55.90,
    -85.50,
    -105.60,
    -129.30,
    -155.10,
    -172.80,
    -195.30,
    -218.70,
    -240.60,
    -266.70,
    -288.00,
    -316.4,
    -330.3,
    -325.4,
    -281.95,
    -160.50,
    -37.88,
    -7.4,
    -1.0
    };

For[i = 1, i < Length[tempData] + 1, i++,
  second[[i, 2]] = tempData[[i]]];
second = second // Reverse;
```

Comment: In your second example `0.17 ~= .16999999999999998`. So it doesn't merge them.

Comment: @Öskå Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Everything is possible ;)

Comment: @Öskå Do you know how? :)

Comment: @Öskå Political statements are off topic here

Comment: @belisarius :D You see what you want in what I say :P

Comment: @BillyJean Quick and dirty `first = N@Round[first, 10^-15];`. Same for `second` and you are all good :)

Comment: **Since people keep answering duplicates** we now have good answers spread across numerous Q&A's including:  [(4332)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4332)
[(16507)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16507)
[(26574)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26574)
[(43683)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43683)
I encourage people to *move any unique answers to the original.* (Delete and repost.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once again not very fancy but it does the job:

```
L = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}};
J = {{0, 1}, {2, 2}, {4, 4}};
Sort@With[{g = GatherBy[Join[L, J], First]}, 
  Thread@{DeleteDuplicates[Flatten@Map[First, g, {2}]], 
          Plus @@@ Map[Last, g, {2}]}]
```

> ```
> {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}
> ```

With the data provided by the OP and `res = Sort[With[{..., Join[first, second]...]` one can have:

```
ListPlot[{res, first, second}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[{PointSize@.02, Red}], Blue, Green},
  Filling -> Axis, Axes -> {False, True}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: When I try this method with the two arrays in the OP, the points around 0.15 are not added

Comment: @BillyJean They are. See [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/H1Mop.png).

Comment: But if I use ListLinePlot on the array, I can see that there are multiple values. But if I show the array using MatrixForm, then I can see there aren't multiple values?!

Comment: @BillyJean Try with a new kernel? Works like a charm for me and all the data seems to be added.

Comment: It's at 0.17 and 0.18, I see it in both the plot and the data

Comment: @BillyJean What about `0.17` and `0.18`? It works fine for me. See [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oF6sD.png).

Comment: When I import the data set from external files they are not added, when I write the arrays in explicitly they are added (?!). Odd.

Comment: @BillyJean Feel free to upload your external file somewhere so one can test. Probably nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Öskå Please see updated OP. One array I generate from an extenral file (upload link provided), the second array I generate using shown code.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the V10 function `Merge`:

```
List @@@ Normal @ Merge[Total][Rule @@@ Join[L, J]]
```

or

```
List @@@ Normal @ Merge[Rule @@@ Join[L, J], Total]
```

or (a variant of @Carlo's answer using `GroupBy` with a different syntax)

```
List @@@  Normal @ GroupBy[Join[L,J], First -> Last, Total]
```

to get

```
(* {{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 3}, {0, 1}, {4, 4}}  *)
```

**Update:** Some timings using Wolfram Programming Cloud:

```
tstdata=RandomInteger[10,{2,100000,2}];

mergeLists[x_, y_] := Module[{f, g, l3}, f[{a_, b_}] /; NumericQ[g@a] := 
  (g[a] += b);
  f[{a_, b_}] := (g[a] := b);l3 = Join[x, y];f /@ l3;{#, g@#} & /@ Union[First /@ l3]]

(res1=mergeLists@@tstdata)//Timing //First
(* 1.889713 *)
(res2=Sort@With[{g = GatherBy[Join@@tstdata, First]},
            Thread@{DeleteDuplicates[Flatten@Map[First, g, {2}]],
            Plus @@@ Map[Last, g, {2}]}])//Timing//First
(* 0.423935 *)
(res2b=With[{g = GatherBy[Join@@tstdata, First]},
            Thread@{DeleteDuplicates[Flatten@Map[First, g, {2}]],
            Plus @@@ Map[Last, g, {2}]}])//Timing//First
(* 0.378943 *)
(res3=List @@@  Normal @ GroupBy[Join@@tstdata, First -> Last, Total])//Timing//First
(* 0.033994  *)
(res4=List@@@Normal[Total /@ GroupBy[Join@@tstdata, First -> Last]])//Timing//First
(* 0.033994 *)
(res5=List @@@ Normal @ Merge[Rule @@@ Join@@tstdata,Total])//Timing//First
(* 9.465561 *)
(res6=List @@@ Normal @ Merge[Total][Rule @@@ Join@@tstdata])//Timing//First
(* 9.496556 *)
Sort@res1==Sort@res2==Sort@res2b==Sort@res3==Sort@res4==Sort@res5==Sort@res6
(* True *)
```

Comment: Nice! Could you provide some comparison indicator for those of us without v10 available? Perhaps just comparing with any other answer to this question...

Comment: @eldo, thanks!!

Comment: @belisarius, good idea -- I will update with some timings.

Comment: @kguler When will you update with some timings? :P

Comment: @Oska, apologies for the delay to post timings -- I do not have the desktop version of V10 yet; I have been using Wolfram Programming Cloud and my internet connection has been too slow recently to do a decent timing experiment. BTW, if you have desktop V10 i would appreciate it very much if you could post your timing results.

Comment: Alas I have _v8_.. :) Maybe @belisarius can do it? :)

Comment: @Öskå Still v9 here ;D

Comment: @belisarius Meh, I thought you wrote some fancy _v10_ answers. I guess you all use the cloud :)

Comment: @Oska, belisarius , I just added some timings.

Answer (score 5):

Just showing some tricks:

```
l1 = {{1, 1}, {8, 2}, {3, 3}};
l2 = {{0, 1}, {8, 3}, {4, 4}};

mergeLists[x_, y_] := Module[{f, g, l3},

  f[{a_, b_}] /; NumericQ[g@a] := (g[a] += b);
  f[{a_, b_}] := (g[a] := b);

  l3 = Join[x, y];
  f /@ l3;
  {#, g@#} &/@ Union[First /@ l3]
  ]

(*{{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {8, 5}}*)
```

Comment: wow, this is fast. You time 0.298017, eldo's time 4.371250

Comment: @molekyla777 eldo's answer uses Replacement rules, which are usually slow

Comment: This only works if the arrays are of the same size

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Also works for non-equal lengths

Comment: @belisarius It doesn't work with my data set, I pasted the two arrays in the OP

Comment: @Öskå Could you please try it now again?

Comment: @belisarius [Perfect](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5Sb8v.png). Or we are both wrong :P

Comment: @belisarius It works now, but 0.17 and 0.18 are not added, just like in the other answer. When I import the data set from external files they are not added, when I write the arrays in explicitly they are added (?!)

Comment: @belisarius Could you help me understand your code better, perhaps with some elaborations on the steps you made? I feel like this is a very clever piece of code, but I'm not smart/advanced enough to know what's going on there.

Comment: @seismatica The style is already explained in a previous answer by Mr.Wizard with comments done by me (or was it the other way?) I'll try to find the original link

Comment: @BillyJean Sounds like a rounding or numerical format problem to me

Comment: @belisarius Would really appreciate it if you do!

Comment: @seismatica I can't find  it,but perhaps executing the following code may enlighten you `f[{a_, b_}] := (g[a] := Print["I was defined as " <> ToString@b]);
f[{1, 2}]; f[{3, 4}]; ?g`

Comment: @seismatica and belisarius: is [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16523/121) perhaps what you were referring to?  There are no comments there but it is a related answer to a related question.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, but it wasn't that one. If I remember well, the answer was yours and I commented to improve it on a similar structure I used here. But I can't remember the main question theme, so it's almost impossible for me to find.

Answer (score 4):

A somewhat shorter way of achieving the same on V10:

```
merge = Total /@ GroupBy[Join[first, second], First -> Last]
```

This would return an Association, but you can still use it in ListPlot. If you don't want an Association

```
List @@@ Normal[merge]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
L = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}};
J = {{0, 1}, {2, 2}, {4, 4}};

Sort@Flatten[Transpose[{J, L}] /. {{a_, b_}, {a_, c_}} :> {{a, b + c}}, 1]
```

> {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}

Comment: That's fancy :) and smarter :P

Comment: @Öskå Thanks - shouldn't be the fastest though for large lists :)

Comment: Only works for two list with no duplicate first entries.

Comment: @John Could you give an example?

Comment: l = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 7}, {3, 3}};
j = {{0, 1}, {2, 5}, {4, 5}, {4, 1}};

Comment: This following slight change seems more general. Sort@Flatten[Transpose[{l, j}], 1] //. {x___, {a_, b_}, {a_, c_}, 
   y___} :> {x, {a, b + c}, y}

Comment: @JohnMcGee oops I didn't see your answer before I posted mine! Why not using `Join` instead of `Transpose` and `Flatten`?

Answer (score 2):

`Sow`, `Reap` implementation

```
t = Join[L, J];
tags = DeleteDuplicates[t[[All, 1]]];
res = Reap[t /. {x_, y_} :> {Sow[y, x]}][[2]];
MapThread[{#1, Total@#2} &, {tags, res}]
(*{{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 3}, {0, 1}, {4, 4}}*)
```

Comment: More terse:  `Reap[Sow@@@Join[J,L],_,{#1,Total@#2}&]//Last`

Answer (score 2):

One-liner:

```
Sort@Join[L,J]//.{a___,{x_,y1_},{x_,y2_},b___}:>{a,{x,y1+y2},b}
```

Testing it on your 2 lists (took about 0.001 in `AbsoluteTiming`)

```
merge=Sort@Join[first,second]//.{a___,{x_,y1_},{x_,y2_},b___}:>{a,{x,y1+y2},b};
ListPlot[{merge,first,second},
PlotLegends->{"merge","first","second"},PlotStyle->AbsolutePointSize/@{8,4,4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an optional approach with more details.
First merge the lists then gather the first coordinates

```
t = Flatten[{l, j}, 1]; f = Union[First[[Transpose[t]]];
```

Next form a ragged array, collecting by the first element.

```
r = Cases[t, {#, _}] & /@ f;
```

Finally collapse the ragged array by summing

```
Total[#[[All, 2]]] & /@ r; rstl=Transpose[{f,s}];
```

I hope that you find this helpful.

Comment: Thanls, but this only works if the arrays are of the same size